# Number magic in multiplication

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

$13837 \cdot ab \cdot 73 = abababab$, where $ab$ is a two digit number. What are the reason or speciality of $13837$ and $73$? Why it is happening

Comment: Exceptional...thanks a lot

Comment: It's better to write $\overline{ab}$ as a two-digit number $10a+b$.

Answer (score 1):

$13837\times73=1010101.$

$1010101\times ab$ gives this form

Answer (score 0):

The explanation is 
$
13837 \cdot ab \cdot 73 = ab \cdot 1010101.
$

When $ab$ has two digits, we have $ab \cdot 1010101 = abababab$.